# Convert string to int array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to convert a string that looks like this,

```
    2,3,4,5,6,20..30
```

to an array of integers. Here is the code I currently have:

```
[string]$a = "2,3,4,5,6,7"
[array]$b = $a.split(",")
[array]$c = foreach($number in $b) {([int]::parse($number))}
```

Which works, but not for the range of 20..30. How do I get that part working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `Invoke-Expression` cmdlet to interpret the `10..30` bit, if the `[int]::Parse()` method call fails.

Here is a complete, working sample.

```
[string]$a = "2,3,4,5,6,7,10..30";
[array]$b = $a.split(",");
[array]$c = foreach($number in $b) {
    try {
        [int]::parse($number)
    }
    catch {
        Invoke-Expression -Command $number;
    }
    }

$c;
```

Answer (score 7):

One-liner (just for fun):

```
$c = "2,3,4,5,6,7,10..30".split(',') | % {iex $_}
```

Comment: Well done, but without looking at trevor's code and explanation I wouldn't have been able to figure out what you were doing here!

Comment: @ImpossibleSqui Thanks but I sincerely hope that you will not use a code that generates an exception when it is not necessary ;)

Comment: I can't say no to one-liners...after experimenting with both your codes, I ended up using yours for it's simplicity.
Thanks again!

Comment: @ImpossibleSqui Glad to help! You can always change your choice answer ;)

Comment: If string not contains comma - split still made it array with one element - it's ok. But after converting  into number it made Int32 variable not Array :(

Comment: @Geograph you can enclose the expression in `@()` to always get an array

Answer (score 0):

Inside of a string, your `..` is taken as-is and is not expanded to a range.

So $a = "1 .. 5" is actually 1 .. 5 and not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

To make your program work, you will have to tokenize not only on `,` but also on `..` and then expand.