# Convert array of integers to string

Tags: arrays, powershell

I found [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925598/convert-string-to-int-array-in-powershell) for doing a string to array:

```
$c = "2,3,4,5,6,7,10..12".split(',') | % {iex $_}
```

How would I do the reverse to convert `$c` back to a string like `"2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12"`? I of course don't require to abbreviate it back to `"2..7,10..12"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `-join`:

```
$c -join ','
```

Comment: Ah! As simple as that, I was making it harder than it need be.